# How do I get Code::Blocks to display .h and .cpp files in the same directory?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am very slowly figuring out Code::Blocks and am trying to set it to my liking.

The gentleman that provided the second answer in this post: [Organization of files in Code Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025898/organization-of-files-in-code-blocks/22326748#22326748) seems to be able to get C::B to display his header and source files in a single directory in the project tree. This is what his project tree looks like (and how I want mine to look):

[image]

However, in my case, anytime I create a header file, C::B displays it in a new directory called 'Headers' (see image below). I should mention that I am keeping the .cpp and .h files together in the same directory when I am creating the files.

[image]

I looked all over environment settings, project properties, C::B documentation, online, tried to ask the poster of the link (but i don't have enough reputation to put comments) and I am stuck. Very stuck.

If you know where the setting in C::B which needs to be changed to display the two file types together (like in the link above), I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: have you tried drag and drop them?

Comment: Yes. Dragging and dropping did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sources` and `Headers` folders that by default appear to contain
respectively the source and header files of a C::B project are virtual
folders that represent the "categories" (header, source) of the files
within.

To disable this virtual organisation of your project:-

- Right-click on your project icon in the project workspace
- From the pop-menu select **Project tree**
- In the **Project tree** sub-menu *un*check the item **Categorize by file types**